# standalone Xbee end device / router?

Tags: wireless, xbee, zigbee

can xbee be used as a standalone device, which can take some input and transfer it to co-ordinator without another microcontroller support? 
I did find one blog where he used xbee directly programmed with ftdi for GPIOs. 
Can anyone please direct me to which xbee is programmable?

http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=130_133&products_id=1105

will this work ?

Comment: You can use the XCTU program from Digi to change the Xbees into programming/API mode, and access their pins making them effectively a standalone microcontroller style unit. They just have limited GPIO/ADC capability.

Answer (score 1):

Most people use Xbees as an all-in-one solution for IOT projects. You have your Xbee device which you connect with a WiFi network. You can also attach your Xbee to one of their cloud-kits. This makes it easy to add sensors or actuators to the Xbee. You can change the behavior of actuators and sensor by using a web interface. This is where the Xbee was developed for.

However I found [here](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Programmable_XBee_-_Getting_Started) that it might be possible to change the Xbee's behavior.